# how to fetch an image from database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am trying to show an image from the database to a new page using php. I am clicking on the image which needs to open in a new page. But everytime a same image is showing on the new page. I want an image in the new page which I clicked in last page. please help me.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "");
    $sdb = mysql_select_db("display_images",$con);
    $sql = "SELECT image FROM `tab1` WHERE 1";
    $mq = mysql_query($sql) or die ("not working query");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($mq) or die("line 44 not working");
    $s = $row['image'];
    echo $row['image'];

    echo '<img src="'.$s.'" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:800px;height:500px " >';
?>
```

Comment: Please stop using mysql, use mysqli (PDO) is it far better and more secure.

Comment: Always use `var_dump()` to check what your variables store, if they store nothing insert your query directly into MySQL using phpMyAdmin and see what data is being selected, if none, fix your query.

Comment: When you want to print errors go about it like that: `die('Error: ' . mysql_error());`

Comment: You need to send the id of the image as query string with link then use SELECT image FROM `tab1` WHERE id='imageid';

Comment: You need to get `id` for identifying which image is clicked and moreover you are not iterating images, it seems you are using very first row coming through query only, this way you will always be getting one image.

Comment: What does your `tab1` table look like? Do you have an image id? You also say that you are opening the image in a new page, could you post the code that creates the link?

Comment: can you please help me with the code..that would be appreciated

Comment: you don't have a where clause (or at least not a significant one), how does your query know which row you are trying to get?

Comment: i have image ids as 1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5.  i want this statement $sql = "SELECT image FROM `tab1` WHERE 1"; to automatically get image id whenever i click an image from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use the below code:

```
<?php

  $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  $coo=mysql_select_db('your_db',$con);
   if(!$coo)
    {
        echo 'error';
    }
   $get='select * from `your_table` where 1';

   $get1=mysql_query($get);

   $r=mysql_num_rows($get1);
   for($j=1;$j<=$r;$j++){
      $ans=mysql_fetch_array($get1);
?>
  <img src="<?php echo $ans['your_field_name']?>" width="200" height ="200" 
   attr="<? php echo $ans['your_field_name']?>" class="image"/>
 <?php } 
 ?>
 <script src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
 <script>   
     $( document ).ready(function(){

      $('.image').click(function(){

         var new_image= $(this).attr('attr');
         window.open( new_image );
    }); 
   });  
 </script>
```

The above code will do that just list out all the images from your table and then when you click a particular image that will displayed in the new window!!Is it your need??
mysql_query() is not preferable...Just for you!!

Comment: I want to show a pic that was clicked. I dont want to show a same pic when i click any image. please help

Comment: you will be displayed more than one image?

Comment: i want the image to be showed which i clicked. but my code is showing the same image everytime whenever i click any image..i want u to please correct my code if there are any errors

Comment: yes I tried but it didnt work. Now whenever i am clicking an image, all the images from the database are showing on the new page. The pic that i clicked is not showing alone.

Comment: have you connect the jquery library file in the <script>? Post your tried code also